# write-host -NoNewline parameter is ignored with powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Starting with WMF 5.1 the `-NoNewLine` option for `Write-Host` is essentially ignored.

**Simple example:**

```
PS C:\> Write-Host "no newline test " -NoNewline
```

**Current Behaviour:**

```
no newline test

PS C:\>
```

**Expected Behavior**

```
no newline test PS C:\>
```

PS version Table is as follows :

```
Name Value 
---- ----- 
PSVersion 5.1.14409.1012 

PSEdition Desktop 

PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...} 

BuildVersion 10.0.14409.1012 

CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000 

WSManStackVersion 3.0 

PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3 

SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1
```

As per Microsoft docs for powershell 5.1, Next Prompt should come in the same line after output of `Write-Host "no newline test" -NoNewline` statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-5.1

Any idea why it is not functioning as expected?

Comment: Combine your command at least 2 times and you'll see the behaviour you expected  `Write-Host "no newline test Line 1 " -NoNewline;Write-Host "no newline test Line 2" -NoNewline`

Comment: by the way - for me behavior is the same and @Olaf it stays the same with your version too - PS puts newline after last statement - it works only on first

Comment: @Drako Of course it does. You will not change the behaviour of the prompt. You only change the behaviour of Write-Host with the parameter.

Comment: @Olaf I have very interesting behavior I did run anther script  and after reading your comment I re-run and got expected behavior while reopening new window of PS and immediately running this I have again wrong behavior - seems like PS glitch :)

Comment: Windows PowerShell 5.1 is no longer under development, so even if it is a bug, it's never going to be fixed. Try it with PowerShell 6 (it appears to be the same) and the official place to report it is https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues or https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues depending which is incorrect

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in powershell 5.1. I have reported the same on powershell github. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7068

Comment: @Drako As far as I understand it you can only change the behaviour of the prompt for outputs in scripts you use. You cannot change the behaviour of the prompt of an interactive console. So if you use it in a script to concatenate outputs it should work.

Comment: @Olaf - possibly you are right - I actually don't do windows already for about 4-5 years - nix only - just tested on my pc :)

Comment: @Drako I have the same in PowerShell 6.0 (but only in VSC) - first time it doesn't insert line break after two `Write-Host -NoNewLine`. Interesting